# Fullscreen <canvas> element on iOS: glitch on scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas

I have a `<canvas>` element with this CSS:

```
canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: black;
}
```

I display funny stuff behind the actual content on a website. On iOs, the address bar hides on scroll. When it hides, the canvas doesn't fill the entire height anymore for a second or so, which is ugly.

[image]

[Here is a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfin0spehikeh0x/iphone-canvas-glitch.m4v?dl=0). Note that I colored the canvas all black to make the point more clear. Normally the canvas is not just black. Note how the content underneath can be seen at the bottom when the address bar hides.

Of course I tried to make the canvas higher than 100% but this has no effect. Even when I set the height to 1000px (and confirm on the console that `$('canvas').height()` returns 1000) the same thing happens. It is as if the canvas element isnt rendered outside of the viewport.

I read up on how to force hide/show the address bar so the transition does not happen but it seems that all methods are outdated. Of course I prefer not to influence the address bar's behaviour.

Here is a [demo](http://formfunk.betelgeuse.uberspace.de/formfunk-sandbox/) showing the problem. The canvas is not black in this demo, it is the wobbly colored thing in the background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not only on ios, I can see this also by resizing my desktop browser and without any relevant code (I won't dig into your page's sources) I won't be able to help

Comment: What desktop browser are you using? What more code than the CSS above do you need? I tested the issue without anything happening in JS which is why I am confident that it is not a JS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

- making the canvas higher than the viewport
- adding the wonderfully hacky `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

It now looks like this:

```
canvas[resize] {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 115%; // Higher than the viewport
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: black;
}
```